# Excel - Format cells with cell value between today() and today()+30

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Why isn't my conditional format working even though it falls in the criteria?

Format only cells that contain

```
Cell value between ="TODAY()+1" and ="TODAY()+30"
```

Cell value is `25/04/2016 (25-Apr-16)`

Which should fall under the criteria as `TODAY()+1 = 21/04/16 and TODAY()+30 = 20/05/16`

It isn't  changing the colour.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `="TODAY() + 1"` results in `"TODAY() + 1"`. It's a string whose literal value is `"TODAY() + 1"`.

Remove the quotes.

Comment: Ah, so simple! I'm sure i didn't add the quotes, i must have missed off the = at the beginning of the formula and its added them.